# Почему в методе класса при вызове требуется ненужный атрибут?TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, классы

Создал один класс и к нему два подкласса. Написал классу метод drop, все было хорошо работал. Потом решил написать второй метод sell. После чего и метод drop и метод sell начали вызывать ошибку пропущенного атрибута cost(цены) он применяется внутри метода, но если его добавлять как атрибут - все равно ошибка.

```
  class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost

    @staticmethod
    def drop(name, container):
        for i, item in enumerate(container):
            if item.name == name:
                del container[i]
                break

    @staticmethod
    def sell(name, container, money):
        for i, item in enumerate(container):
            if item.name == name:
                del container[i]
            money += item.cost


class Sword(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, damage, cost):
        Item.__init__(self, name, cost)
        self.damage = damage

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nDamage: {}\nCost: {}".format(self.name, self.damage, self.cost)


class Armor(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, defend, cost):
        Item.__init__(self, name, cost)
        self.defend = defend

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nProtect: {}\nCost: {}".format(self.name, self.defend, self.cost)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wooden_sword = Sword("Деревянный меч", 2, 10)
    iron_sword = Sword("Железный меч", 2, 20)
    steel_sword = Sword("Стальной меч", 3, 30)
    mur_sword = Sword("Мурмеч", 5, 50)
    swords = [wooden_sword, iron_sword, steel_sword, mur_sword]
    leather_armor = Armor("Кожаная броня", 1, 5)
    iron_armor = Armor("Железная броня", 2, 15)
    steel_armor = Armor("Стальная броня", 3, 25)
    magick_steel_armor = Armor("Броня из магической стали", 4, 45)
    armors = [leather_armor, iron_armor, steel_armor, magick_steel_armor]
inventory = [wooden_sword, leather_armor]
container = inventory
money = 0
while True:
user_input = input("Хотите выкинуть предмет?\n")
if user_input.lower() == "да":
    for i in inventory:
        print(i)
    item = input("Выберите предмет: ")
    Item(item).drop(item, inventory)
    for i in inventory:
        print("\n" + str(i))
user_input = input("Хотите продать предмет?\n")
if user_input.lower() == "да":
    for i in inventory:
        print(i)
    item = input("Выберите предмет: ")
    Item(item).sell(item, inventory, money)
    for i in inventory:
        print("\n" + str(i))
```

А сама ошибка собственно вот:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AppSuppoRT/PycharmProjects/untitled/сына/1.py", line 67, in 
<module>
Item(item).sell(item, inventory, money)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cost'
```

Спасибо за помощь, и да я знаю что отступы странно раставленны пришлось вручную их выставлять так как примером кода плохо получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку вызывают не `drop` и `sell`, а функция `__init__` класса `Item`. Фрагмент `Item(item)` в строке 67 создает новый объект этого класса и для инициализации нужны два параметра - `name` и `cost`. А дан только один - `item` (который получается `name`).

Строки

```
Item(item).drop(item, inventory)
Item(item).sell(item, inventory, money)
```

заменить на

```
Item.drop(item, inventory)
Item.sell(item, inventory, money)
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но если не сложно можно на примере строки показать как надо, а то я все таки не совсем понимаю как нужно изменить. Во что надо превратить вот это? Item(item).drop(name, inventory) и Item(name).sell(name, inventory, money)

Comment: добавил. У Вас неправильная работа со staticmethod..

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь и ответы помимо "ха идиот, это же легко".